# Is running HM10 on a soft-serial enable the Low Energy charecteristics ? If so, how can the UUIDs and GATT profiles be tweaked in this case ?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, hm-10

I've been tinkering with the HM-10 board for a few weeks now, trying to push data from phone to module and vice-versa. The ultimate goal was to enable the BLE mode and tweak with the characteristics and GATT profiles. I'm pretty new to this domain so can anyone help me out ?

And is there any way we can interface the HM-10 with the hardware rx-tx channel instead of soft-serial ?

Comment: Yes there is a way, but you need to tell us what you tried, what code-language skills you have and what you want to achieve.

Comment: I've tried the basic "posting data and receiving on a mobile" tutorials and tried various AT commands using an Arduino Uno (with Arduino IDE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is still not very clear, but i think you mean sending AT-commands over BLE-radio.

To make this possible you have to change the MODE using serial connection.
In standard mode the device can only be configured over the serial connection (pins RXD and TXD) using AT commands.

```
AT+MODE0: It only accepts AT-commands over the serial connection (RXD/TXD) 
          until a central device connects to the module.

AT+MODE1: Same as MODE0, once a connection is established,
          AT-commands can be sent over BLE and manipulate some PIO pins on
          the device.

AT+MODE2: Same as MODE0, once a connection is established,
          AT-commands can be sent over BLE.
```

To test it just send a string to hm-10 as "AT\r\n" and it will respond with OK.
Update:
You cannot change the services and characteristics with AT-commands.
There are a lot of other things you can change,like advertising, setup a beacon and change a lot of settings.
For a full list of AT commands and more see the official data sheet:
http://www.jnhuamao.cn/bluetooth41_en.zip

Comment: That clears my second part of the question. How can I alter/add the custom profiles for HM-10 ? Is it even possible with Arduino programming or is it firmware level stuff ?

Comment: Updated my answer.